# Clonezilla fails while cloning/imaging the entire HDD

Tags: linux, images, cloning, clonezilla

I am using Clonezilla Live DVD to image my entire HDD consisting of several partitions. An overview of the partitions can be seen in the following excerpt from the log file of Clonezilla:

```
Machine: Dell System XPS L502X
sda (500GB_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda1 (104M_vfat_A.(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda2 (19.5G_ntfs_RECOVERY(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda3 (125G_ntfs_OS(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda5 (270G_ntfs_DATA(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda6 (27.1G_ext4(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
sda8 (20G_ext4(In_TOSHIBA_MK5061GS)_TOSHIBA_MK5061GSY_513DT5MQT)
```

I should point out that the latter partitions sda5, sda6 and sda8 reside in an extended partition and sda7 is the Linux-SWAP partition. In both of my trials there were errors while trying to image sda6 the `root` partition for my Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 32-bit installation. I have attached the saving error log file to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5E75srjg). I have no clue about the reason for this behaviour and would like to learn the default behaviour of Clonezilla for SWAP partitions(**sda7**), does it save them too?

Answer (score 2):

The imaging error on sda6 can be avoided by ensuring source disk file checking is on. Check the FAQ: http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/118_fs_not_clean_mounted.faq#118_fs_not_clean_mounted.faq .

Comment: I looked at the link, are you sure that this is the culprit? Will using the flags mentioned remedy the problem? On my other PC I had not trouble with the same version of Clonezilla.

Comment: Furthermore, can it have something to do with HDD going into some sort of sleep mode?